# a promise was created in a handler at ... but was not returned from it

Tags: javascript, typescript, bluebird, es6-promise

I am trying to resolve this [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap) warning in [BsDropDownState](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/dropdown/bs-dropdown.state.ts)
I am using angular 4.3.3, and bluebird 3.5.0

[Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) produces the below warning.

> Warning: a promise was created in a handler at ... but was not returned from it, see [google docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it)

What I have observed is that any promise created in this fashion produces the same warning, regarless of whether or not it's even called?

```
var BsDropdownState = (function () {
    function BsDropdownState() {
        var _this = this;
        this.direction = 'down';

        /* this empty promise that is never called produces the same warning */
        this.test = new Promise(function (resolve) { resolve("TEST"); return null; })
     }
}
```

**What's the correct pattern here?**

The full original typescript is as follows

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BsComponentRef } from '../component-loader/bs-component-ref.class';

@Injectable()
export class BsDropdownState {
  direction: 'down' | 'up' = 'down';
  autoClose: boolean;
  isOpenChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  isDisabledChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  toggleClick = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  /**
   * Content to be displayed as popover.
   */
  dropdownMenu: Promise<BsComponentRef<any>>;
  resolveDropdownMenu: (componentRef: BsComponentRef<any>) => void;

  constructor() {
    // here lies the sleeping warning...
    this.dropdownMenu = new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.resolveDropdownMenu = resolve;
    });
  }
}
```

**edit**

I have tried adding return values to the generated `.js`. The warning remains

```
var BsDropdownState = (function () {
    function BsDropdownState() {
        var _this = this;
        this.direction = 'down';
        this.isOpenChange = new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["EventEmitter"]();
        this.isDisabledChange = new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["EventEmitter"]();
        this.toggleClick = new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["EventEmitter"]();
        this.dropdownMenu = new Promise(function (resolve) {
            _this.resolveDropdownMenu = resolve;
            resolve("TESTING");
            return null;
        });
        return null;
    }
```

**edit**

Here is (some of) the [stack trace](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6279e50d78554781111053e41cafcc8ca50ecc97/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L105):
[`core.es5.js`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6279e50d78554781111053e41cafcc8ca50ecc97/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L105)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: correct, because `function BsDropdownState() {` doesn't return anything

Comment: its' a constructor though? I guess that's what's throwing me, what would the correct pattern be?

Comment: Are you calling this constructor directly somewhere, or is it being called by some automatic process? If it's the former, can you show us the code where it's being called?

Comment: @JLRishe, I am adding the stack trace through core.es5.js

Comment: @Jim not sure what your use case is, but the usual pattern is to create a promise, use `.then` to utilize the value `resolve`d from the promise, or .`catch` any error. And optionally await the promise. Some questions arise from your code are: 1. What is the need for storing the promise if you don't need to pass it on? 2. What is the use for `this.resolveDropdownMenu = resolve;`? Again I am not sure about your use case, just trying to help based on the given code.

Comment: @Jim where is `createProviderInstance` called? Post the complete stack trace please. It's somewhere in a `then` handler, like `.then(function() { createProviderInstance(); }`. It's there that you need to add the `return null;`.

Comment: @Bergi It looks like it's being called in that first screenshot (the `new ctor()` line). Seems like OP's code is being plugged into Angular's DI framework and the actual code instantiating his constructor is within Angular.

Comment: @JLRishe Yes, but to my knowledge Angular doesn't use Bluebird, so somewhere there must be a call into the DI routine that's placed inside a custom handler.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `resolve`, and `reject` to return a fulfilled and rejected promise. The general schema is as below:

```
const myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // do something asynchronous which eventually calls either:
  //
  //   resolve(someValue); // fulfilled
  // or
  //   reject("failure reason"); // rejected
});
```

Check [the source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise) for more details.

Hope this helps.